# Why is memcheck reporting memory leak (double linked list)?

Tags: c, while-loop, memory-leaks, dynamic-memory-allocation, doubly-linked-list

Working on simple double linked list.

```
struct list_node {
   struct list_node *prev, *next;
   int data;
};

struct list {
   struct list_node *first, *last;
};
```

With creation and pushing as follows:

```
struct list *list_create(void) {
    struct list *_list = malloc(sizeof(struct list));
    if(_list == NULL) {
        die("Memory allocation error for list_create\n");
    }
    _list->first = NULL;
    _list->last = NULL;
    return _list;
}
void list_push(struct list *list, int item_data) {
    struct list_node *_node = malloc(sizeof(struct list_node));
    if(_node == NULL) {
        die("Memory allocation error for list_push\n");
    }
    _node->prev = NULL;
    _node->next = NULL;
    _node->data = item_data;

    //empty list case
    if(list->last == NULL) {
        list->first = _node;
        list->last = _node;
    }
    else {
        _node->prev = list->last;
        list->last->next = _node;
        list->last = _node;
    }
}
```

One push works but two successive ones cause memory leak - of size of a node.
What am I missing here?

For a completion here is my `free` for the list - and I am calling it in my code:

```
void list_destroy(struct list *list) {
    if (list->first != NULL) {
        struct list_node *p = list->first;
        //if one node list
        if(list->first == list->last) {
            list->first = NULL;
            list->last = NULL;
            free(p);
            p = NULL;
        }
        else {
            while (p->next) {
                struct list_node *q = p;
                p = p->next;
                free(q);
                q = NULL;
            }
        }
    }
    free(list);
}
```

[SOLVED] Bug was in `list_destroy` - last time through `while(p->next)` left last `p` node not properly handled. Thanks everybody!

Comment: There is no `free()` in the code you posted anywhere.

Comment: There's no need for `p = NULL` and `q = NULL` in `list_destroy()`, since those variables go away shortly after the assignments.

Comment: In the code that is using that linked list I call `list_destroy`  - I added implementation above. I guess the bug is there.

Comment: `while (p->next)` That doesn't free the last node as `p->next` will be NULL for that node.

Comment: Good catch - thanks kaylum - and everybody else! Off by one.

Comment: You can/should post an answer to your own question instead of putting it into the question itself.

Comment: @Tom N If the question resolved then select the best answer to close the question.:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The memory leaks are produced by the function `list_destroy` in this while loop

```
        while (p->next) {
            struct list_node *q = p;
            p = p->next;
            free(q);
            q = NULL;
        }
```

The last node of the list is not freed due to the condition of the while loop

```
        while (p->next) {
```

because for the last node the data member `next` is equal to `NULL`.

There is no sense to split the function into two parts. The function can look the following way

```
void list_destroy(struct list *list) {
    while ( list->first )
    {
        struct list_node *p = list->first;
        list->first = list->first->next;
        free( p );
    }

    free( list );
}
```

It would be better to pass the pointer list by reference through a pointer to it as for example

```
void list_destroy(struct list **list) {
    struct list_node *current = ( *list )->first;

    while ( current )
    {
        struct list_node *p = current;
        current = current->next;
        free( p );
    }

    free( *list );
    *list = NULL;
}
```

In this case after the function execution the pointer to the list in the caller will be equal to NULL.

Also you could write a function that clears the list. It can look the following way

```
void list_clear(struct list *list) {
    while ( list->first )
    {
        struct list_node *p = list->first;
        list->first = list->first->next;
        free( p );
    }

    list->last = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Vlad - much appreciated style pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Vlad from Moscow wrote a cleaner version.
I'd like to add "defensive programming".
It's dangerous to assume `create()` has been called before `push()` or `destroy()`.
In fact, you can avoid a tough-to-find bug (using a pointer in the calling code after it's been free()'d.) Always check 'passed-in' arguments.

In the calling code:

```
myList = list_destroy( myList );
```

and return something that can be used.

```
list_t *list_destroy( list_t *pList ) {
    assert( pList != NULL );
    // iterate releasing alloc'd blocks...
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: If you want to program defensively then you must not use assertions for your checks, as they may be compiled right out of your program.  Assertions are more documentary than anything else, providing for expressing the code's (assumed) invariants.  They can also help you during development to confirm that those invariants hold.  But if an assertion ever fails then that indicates a programming error, and finding those is called "debugging" not "defensive programming".

Comment: Call it what you want.
During 'development', generous use of `assert()` saves hours otherwise spent 'debugging'.
Regardless of the specificity of an error message, 'release' executables shouldn't fail with some excuse about "NULL pointer detected in function 'X' ".
Using `assert()` is defensive. Not using 'assert()` is "whistling in the dark."

Comment: I use assertions and recommend their (proper) use, but it is very important to understand what they actually do.  I ordinarily take the term "defensive programming" to describe practices that actively ensure runtime safety.  Assertions are the wrong tool for that.  To the extent that you engage in defensive programming -- which you should, at least in external-facing functions -- that goes alongside.

Comment: To end on good terms, I propose replacing "defensive" with "humble"... I agree. The value of `assert()` lies in helping the coder in his/her battle against his/her own worst enemy: unjustified overconfidence. :-)